# Neat argument for why $A(4,3)=2$

Tags: coding-theory

$A(n,d)$ is the size of a largest code of length $n$ and minimum distance at least $d$.
(Im using Hamming distance as my distance)

Im trying to show from first principles that $A(4,3)=2$

Its easy to show $A(4,3)\geq 2$, just give a code of size 2 that has length $n$ and min.dist $\geq 3$

So I need to argue that $A(4,3)\leq 2$ and this can be done by showing that there is no code of size 3 satisfying the conditions. I can see why this is a case but Im struggling to write a neat argument which proves a code with length $4$ and min distance $3$ can't have size $3$.

Comment: Without loss of generality, let one of the words in the code be $0000$. Then any other word must have at least three $1$s. Can there be more than one of those?